# How to match array with object to retrieve matched elements?

Tags: jquery

var Array = [Activism,Netherlands,France,Politics];

data-topic="Activism African Cinema and Culture Biography Conflicts Colonialism History Human Rights Law and Justice Politics Society Women France Netherlands South-Africa English-spokelang cinephil 1001011"

i want to match my array values in li data-topic if its match all the values. then i want t show result. somebody knows how to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to find the element of `Array` that is not present in `data-topic`. So whenever you get at least one element of `Array` not in `data-topic` you can confirm that and show your result accordingly. Here is the code snippet that works for you

```
var arrayData = ['Activism','Netherlands','France','Politics'];

var data_topic="Activism African Cinema and Culture Biography Conflicts Colonialism History Human Rights Law and Justice Politics Society Women France Netherlands South-Africa English-spokelang cinephil 1001011";

var isMatched = true;
for(var i=0; i<arrayData .length; i++){
  //if the arrayData element is not contained in the data_topic
  if(data_topic.indexOf(arrayData [i]) === -1){
    isMatched = false;
    //do not loop further
    break;
  }
}

if(isMatched){
  alert('data-topic contains all Array element');
}
```

For your simplicity, here is the link to [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jkqs0oq5/1/)

You can notice that i have renamed the variable `Array` as `arrayData` since the `Array` can be misunderstood as a inbuilt keyword. Also, `data-topic` is changed to `data_topic` for proper variable declaration in javascript.

Comment: Don't name the array `Array`, this will cause serious problems, because that's reserved, just like `String`, `Number`, `Object` etc.

Comment: But i have just made is as Array to match with the same name as in question. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: I know, and your answer is good, but it would be a shame if this part would break other parts of his code. So suggesting a rename of the variable in your answer would make it even better :)

Comment: Sure, have my up vote! To complete everything, you could even improve your answer a little bit more and put the code into a snippet, instead of linking to a fiddle!